# Is it possible to plot two errorbars on one figure?

Tags: matlab

I need to plot two data vectors with errorbars on one figure. errorbar() function does it, but only for one data set. Is there a way to plot second graph on the same figure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Been an idiot, forgive me. I just needed to pass in a two-dimensional matrices instead of vectors.

Comment: also: take a look at `hold` in the documentation.